# exclude certain categories from posts

Tags: posts, categories

I've got a page which displays the latest posts, but I'm trying to exclude posts from certain categories. This is my code:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?>  
<?php
$args      = array(
    'numberposts' => 2,
    'post_status' => "publish",
    'post_type'   => "post",
    'orderby'     => "post_date",
    'exclude'     => "8"
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
echo '<div class="latest_new_posts">';
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="blog-date-news"><span><?php the_date( 'd/m/Y' ); ?></span></div>
        <div class="blog-container">
            <div class="news-blog-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>
            <div class="news-blog-excerpt"> <?php echo excerpt( 500 ); ?> </div>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So I'm trying to exlude category ID 8 from it but it's still showing.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`exclude` in `get_posts()` refers to *post* IDs, they are not interchangeable with *category* IDs.

The argument you are looking for is probably `'category__not_in' => [ 8 ]`